# Ember - observer in previous route fires when property set in didTransition hook of next route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my index route, I have an observer that fires an action when the user object is set in the session service, as shown below. This works fine- the console logs 'index route observer fired' and the action fires.

**routes/index**

```js
session: Ember.inject.service(),
  sendTheAction: function() {
    console.log('index route observer fired');
    this.send('checkLicense');
  }.observes('session.user'),

  actions: {
    checkLicense: function() {
      if (this.get('session.user.email)) {
          //get the user's email and send off an AJAX request.
        }
      },
    }
```

I also have a logout route which (among other things) sets session.user to an empty object, and then transitions to the login route. I simply use a link-to helper pointing to 'logout' to initiate this.

**routes/logout**

```js
session: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    didTransition: function() {
      this.set('session.user', {});
      this.transitionTo('login');
    }
  }
```

If I am in the index route and I click logout, the transition to logout begins. Then, when session.user is set to {} in the logout route's didTransition hook, the observer in the index route fires. The console logs 'index route observer fired' but then I get a console error saying

```
Error while processing route: logout Nothing handled the action 'checkLicense'.
```

I'm not sure how the observer in the previous route can still be fired by a change in the logout route's didTransition hook, as I thought didTransition only fired when the transition was fully resolved.

I think that it is then looking for the action "checkLicense" in the logout route.

Can anyone clarify why that observer still fires, and how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observer still fires and this is the expected behavior. The reason is; routes are SINGLETONs; they are not destroyed upon transitions. So; if you define an observer within a route and watch for values that might be updated by other routes, components, controllers, etc. then your observer will still work!!! So; be careful about using observers within singletons (controllers, services, routest, etc.).

I created a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a0a914986391ead5ae845cb9c6eee3b8?openFiles=routes.my-route.js%2C) that shows the exact case you mentioned. The valid question here in fact is "why is the `send` action within `index.js` is delegated to the other route?" Here is the [answer](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_send) from the Ember.js api. It says "Sends an action to the router, which will delegate it to the currently active route..." in `send` method definition. So; the error occurs; because current active route is not `index` anymore; action is not found!

So; what can you do? Why are throwing an action to yourself within `index.js`? Just make a normal function call!!! If you still need the action; you can also call the same function from within the action. See the [modified twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/207d9a672843c3e070366ae86713ac14?openFiles=routes.index.js%2C) in order to see what I mean.

To sum up; observers within singletons will work no matter what if the dependent key(s) get(s) updated! Hope; it is all clear now. Best Regards.

Comment: _Why are throwing an action to yourself within index.js? Just make a normal function call!!!_ I think that's the point.

Comment: I understand this perfectly now. Thanks for the excellent answer, and workaround.